# integral of inverse powers of distance

Tags: calculus, integration, reference-request, soft-question

I have encountered some integrals of this form

$\int  d^n y \ \frac{1}{\Pi_{i=1}^m|x_i-y|^{p_i}}$

where $x_i,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $|x-y|$ is the usual Cartesian distance. Also $\Sigma_{i=1}^m p_i>n$ so the integral won't blow up at infinity.

It feel like such integral may have already been well studied (at least for the simple case when all $p_i=1$ ?) Does it have a name pr where can I find something about it?

If none, how can I calculate this integral?